# PLSQL type file generator from xsd

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-xml-db

Is there any API, command or tools available, which generates plsql type file in .sql format( so that i can keep in version control ) which may undergo changes for multiple releases, for the given xsd schema  ?. Assumption is PLSQL SP takes and returns XML clob object.

Comment: So you have the XML schema already stored in DB, and you want to fetch its definition, right? You can look it up in `ALL_XML_SCHEMAS` view. Or use `DBMS_METADATA` to get DDL: `select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('XMLSCHEMA', :schema_url) from dual`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a procedure `DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.REGISTERSCHEMA` 
 which based on .xsd ( and when parameter gentypes is set to TRUE) generates also database types.

However I'm afraid, that you have to save the generated DDL of these types just manually after they are generated.